# Filter dataframe rows which contribute to X% of values in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I have a dataframe:

```
df
Col1   Col2   Col3
A      B      5
C      D      4
E      F      1
```

I want to see only those rows which contribute to 90% of Col3. In this case the expected output will be :

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
A      B      5
C      D      4
```

I tried the below but is doesnt work as expected:

```
df['col3'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

Is there any solution for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```py
df = df[df.Col3 > 0] # optionally remove 0 valued rows
df = df.sort_values(by='Col3', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
totals = df.Col3.cumsum()
cutoff = totals[totals >= df.Col3.sum() * .7].idxmin()
print(df[:cutoff + 1])
```

Output

```
  Col1 Col2  Col3
0    A    B     5
1    C    D     4
```

Comment: I checked by putting 9 as the value in the first row followed by 0 and 1, it still shows me 2 rows when the condition should be satisfied by first row only. Can you check and comment, please?

Comment: I am sorry for being a drag. if I put values as [6,3,1] the most contributing should be [6,3] which is correct and as per my expectations. but if the values in order are [6,1,3] then it shows [6,1] which is correct but not as per expectation. I tried sorting after creating the dataframe, but in that case, I don't know why it shows all 3 rows.

Comment: @RSM No worries. Please provide the expected answer for `[6, 1, 3]` and explain.

Comment: Thanks, so the expectation in the above scenario is that from the dataset, I need to find the rows contributing most to the 70% of the total value. so if the values are [6,3,1] then between values [6,1] and [6,3] the most contributing will be [6,3] cos [6,3] contributes more (90%) to the total than [6,1] (70%).  I hope I am able to explain it properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218471/discussion-between-balaji-ambresh-and-rsm).

Answer (score 0):

@RSM,  When you say 90% of the data, do you want the calculation of 90% to always start from the top or do you need it to be random ?

```py
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   from io import StringIO

   d = '''Col1   Col2   Col3
   A      B      5
   C      D      4
   E      F      1'''

   df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

   total_value = df['Col3'].sum()
   target_value = 0.9 * total_value
   df['Cumulative_Sum'] = df['Col3'].cumsum()

   desired_df = df.loc[df['Cumulative_Sum'] <=target_value]
   print(desired_df)
```